# Jekyll Localized Host

Tags: jekyll

I'm pretty sure it's not possible but does anyone know of a configuration that can localize the exported files in Jekyll so that the `_site` content can run independent of a web host?

I want to use Jekyll to develop a site, and deliver the contents of the `_site` folder for hosting, but I will not have the hosting information ahead of time. So I would like to be able to run the `index.html` file in the `_site` folder directly from the Desktop and have the site work properly. That way I can deliver the files and the site will run using relative paths/links regardless of where the files end up being hosted.

Answer (score 0):

This possible but you need to know where your generated site will be located on the filesystem. This, because of the relative links pointing to resources (js, css, images).

For example a site generated at `/home/user/www/_site`, index page will be serve in your brower at `file:///home/user/www/_site/index.html`, so you'll have to set `baseurl` in `_config.yml` to `baseurl: /home/user/www/_site` in order to have you site working.

On windows it can be `baseurl: /C:/Users/New/www/_site`